# Unable to change datasource in charts in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am using Superset for visualizations. In charts, there is an option to "change datasource" but when I click it gives an error "An error occurred". In production server superset is using postgres to store metadata and another postgres server as datasource and gunicorn to start superset.
I tried same setup with default database (sqllite) to store superset metadata and no gunicorn, then "change datasource" option is working fine.
Does anyone know what can be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this ? Or got to know what is the error.
I am also facing the same issue and running superset version 0.35.2

Comment: @Dharam: I am unable to find any solution for this. I raised in github community also but got no further response.

Comment: Can you please provide some logs on this error, it works fine for me ? , any steps to reproduce this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your set up was on HTTPS you may be running into [this issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/8160).

The workaround should be to configure superset to run properly behind a load balancer, as per [these instructions](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#configuration-behind-a-load-balancer).

Comment: Setting up parameter "ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True" in config helped me.
Thanks @Cory